# WebService em javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, web-service

Como consumir um Web Service por javascript utilizando o Visual Studio?

Dei uma pesquisada e encontrei um modo de realizar com Jquery porém nunca utilizei este antes.

Necessito consumir este Web Service para buscar informações como Endereços etc. Já possuo o mesmo.

Comment: É muito abrangente a pergunta, tem muitas maneiras. A ideal acho que seria trabalhar com protocolo REST, que é possível utilizar JSON pra consumir o serviço do seu servidor através de simples requisições XHR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achei isso, talvez te ajuda com o WSDL: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-wsajax/

Utilize o método [`ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) do jquery.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "url-do-webservice"});
```

E use um dos callbacks de retorno para obter a resposta do mesmo. Exemplo:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "url-do-webservice",
  success: function (data) { /* data contém o que foi retornado pelo webservice */; }
 });
```

Answer (score 7):

```
function ChamaMetodoDoWebService() 
{              
    try 
    {    
       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "http://webserviceURL.asmx/nomeDoMetodo",
         data: "{'parametro: valor'}", // somente se o método exigir parâmetros se não é so deixar 'data: "{}"'
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(msg) { 
               // seu código quando o retorno for sucesso
               alert(msg.d);
         },
         failure: function(msg) { 
               // seu código quando falhar
               alert('Erro!');
         }
      });
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        alert('Ocorreu um erro ao tentar chamar o método do WebService, erro encontrado: ' + e);
    }
}
```

Mais detalhes [aqui](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295492/call-c-sharp-webservices-from-javascript-and-consume-it-json-format).

Comment: Cara, tentei utilizar esta função porém me deparei que o webservice é WSDL. http://www.byjg.com.br/site/webservice.php/ws/cep?WSDL
Teria alguma outra forma?

Comment: @Will cara estou tentando consumir aqui esse serviço do `byjg` só que ta dificil rs, complicado que quando eu tento enviar um soapEnvelope no `POST` e contentType `xml` o navegador troca o `POST` pra `OPTIONS` por causa do `cross domain`, esse problema [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099787/jquery-ajax-post-sending-options-as-request-method-in-firefox). Você só pode fazer por javascript mesmo?

Comment: Pois é cara, travei com este Web Service ai, fui para uma opção alternativa estou utilizando este aqui: cep.republicavirtual.com.br
neste caso usando json ja resolve o problema, vou postar o código aqui na resposta.

Comment: @Will vi que você mudo de WebService, agora com o `callback` realmente vai funcionar

Comment: valeu pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Ficou assim:

```
    function consultacep() {
        cep = DSCEP.GetText()
        cep = cep.replace(/\D/g, "")
        url = "http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?cep=" + cep + "&formato=jsonp&callback=correiocontrolcep"
        s = document.createElement('script')
        s.setAttribute('charset', 'utf-8')
        s.src = url
        document.querySelector('head').appendChild(s)
    }

    function correiocontrolcep(valor) {
        if (valor.erro == 'undefined') {
            lblMensagem.SetText('CEP não encontrado');
            return;
        };
        DSENDERECO.SetText(valor.logradouro)
        DSBAIRRO.SetText(valor.bairro)
        DSCIDADE.SetText(valor.cidade)
        CDESTADO.SetValue(valor.uf)
    }
```