# Consumir webservice dinamicamente

Tags: c#, web-service

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Asp.net+c# que irá acessar alguns webservices públicos. Gostaria de fazer algo flexível e de fácil manutenção futura. Eu pensei em chamar o webservice passando seu endereço e parâmetros de entrada e armazenar o resultado em uma lista dinâmica.

É possível acessar um webservice e receber o resultado de forma dinâmica, ou seja, sem precisar fazer referencia do webservice no Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu precisei de algo assim a algum tempo atrás, e obtive excelentes resultados com essa função:

```
    [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermissionAttribute(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Unrestricted = true)]
    internal static object CallWebService(string webServiceAsmxUrl, string serviceName, string methodName, object[] args)
    {

        // Veja http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/39138d08-aa08-4c0c-9a58-0eb81a672f54/adding-a-web-reference-dynamically-at-runtime?forum=csharpgeneral

        System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();

        // Connect To the web service

        System.IO.Stream stream = client.OpenRead(webServiceAsmxUrl + "?wsdl");

        // Now read the WSDL file describing a service.

        var description = System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription.Read(stream);

        ///// LOAD THE DOM /////////

        // Initialize a service description importer.

        var importer = new System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescriptionImporter();

        importer.ProtocolName = "Soap12"; // Use SOAP 1.2.

        importer.AddServiceDescription(description, null, null);

        // Generate a proxy client.

        importer.Style = System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescriptionImportStyle.Client;

        // Generate properties to represent primitive values.

        importer.CodeGenerationOptions = System.Xml.Serialization.CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateProperties;

        // Initialize a Code-DOM tree into which we will import the service.

        var nmspace = new System.CodeDom.CodeNamespace();

        var unit1 = new System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit();

        unit1.Namespaces.Add(nmspace);

        // Import the service into the Code-DOM tree. This creates proxy code that uses the service.

        var warning = importer.Import(nmspace, unit1);

        if (warning == 0) // If zero then we are good to go
        {


            // Generate the proxy code

            var provider1 = System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

            // Compile the assembly proxy with the appropriate references

            string[] assemblyReferences = new string[5] { "System.dll", "System.Web.Services.dll", "System.Web.dll", "System.Xml.dll", "System.Data.dll" };

            var parms = new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters(assemblyReferences);

            var results = provider1.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parms, unit1);

            // Check For Errors

            if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerError oops in results.Errors)
                {


                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("========Compiler error============");

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(oops.ErrorText);

                }

                throw new System.Exception("Compile Error Occured calling webservice. Check Debug ouput window.");

            }

            // Finally, Invoke the web service method

            object wsvcClass = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(serviceName);

            var mi = wsvcClass.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);

            return mi.Invoke(wsvcClass, args);

        }

        else
        {

            return null;

        }

    }
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
    string link = "http://localhost:19656/serviço.asmx";

    object[] args = { "teste" };

    var ws = CallWebService(link, "MeuServiço", "MeuMetodo", args);

    if (ws != null)
    {
       str = ws.ToString(); // Resultado
    }
```

Comment: Exatamente o que preciso! Tks!

Comment: Que bom eu ter ajudado; abraços

Answer (score 0):

Dependendo da [tecnologia do WebService](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service#Tecnologias_Utilizadas) você consegue fazer as requisições apenas usando JQuery passando valores normais ou até mesmo com JSON.

Exemplo de chamada de WebService passando os valores por JSON:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://webserviceURL.asmx/nomeDoMetodo",
  data: "{'parametro: valor'}", // somente se o método exigir parâmetros se não é so deixar 'data: "{}"'
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) { 
    // seu código quando o retorno for sucesso
    alert(msg.d);
  },
  failure: function(msg) { 
    // seu código quando falhar
    alert('Erro!');
  }
});
```

Esse código eu postei [aqui também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5434/webservice-em-javascript/5438#5438). Fora que você pode trabalhar com `jsonp` e `crossdomain` só informando eles, veja mais sobre o [$.ajax aqui](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Outros exemplos, fazendo requisição com o `$.get` ou pode ser com o `$.post`:

```
$.get("http://urlSite/webservice.asmx", { valor: "foo"},
  function(data){
    alert("Retorno: " + data);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Outra alternativa é usar orientação a objeto em sua forma mais pura, ou seja, definir uma interface. Ex.:

```
public interface IMeuServicoExterno {
  IList<MeuResultado> MinhaChamada(MeuTipoQueRepresentaMeuRequest inputParams);
}
```

Em seguida, fazer uma classe concreta, pode ser num assembly externo e esse sim faz a referência ao Web Service externo. Você pode escolher a implementação em tempo de execução, utilizando um container de injeção de dependência ou mesmo um design pattern "Strategy". É uma forma de manter a implementação dinâmica inclusive se o meio de implementação não for o web service em si.

A essência disso é o conceito de [Inversão de dependências](http://ericlemes.com/2013/04/08/unclebob-dependencyinversion/), um dos fundamentos da POO.

Comment: Bacana Eric! Vou tentar implementar usando esses conceitos... Valeu!