# Consumir um serviço asmx a partir de um rest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asmx

Como eu faço para passar um objeto que tenho num **REST** para um **ASMX**?
Tenho essa controller no REST que tem o objeto(cliente) que desejo enviar para um **ASMX**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class OptOutClientController : Controller
{
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   private readonly IOptOutService _service;
   public OptOutClientController(IOptOutService service)
   {
        _service = service;
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public OptOutCliente Unsubscribe([FromBody]OptOutCliente cliente)
   {
      if (cliente == null)
         throw new OptOutException("Informar os dados do cliente OptOut!");

      var valida = _service.Process(cliente);

      BasicHttpBinding httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
      EndpointAddress wsUrl = new 
             EndpointAddress("http://localhost:64460/meuservico.asmx");

      //ServicoWSClient soapClient = new ServicoWSClient(httpBinding, wsUrl);

      return cliente;
  }
}
```

Como eu passo esse **cliente** pro outro lado?

Comment: Quando você adiciona a referência ao serviço externo ele "importa" as classes de reflexão/contrato utilizadas pelo mesmo, assim como cria a classe de Client, comentada em seu código

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, deixa-me ver se entendi. A classe **ServicoWSClient** é uma classe existente no serviço a ser consumido, certo?

Comment: ela é gerada quando você adiciona a referência do serviço. É isso ou vai precisar fazer um post com o XML especificado no wsdl, assim como fazer o par se do XML que receberá no retorno

Comment: Pode ser através da referência do serviço: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb628649.aspx Ou pode ser igual este exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5670/consumir-webservice-dinamicamente